# Not able to install apple watch app

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I created an application for Apple watch Model **MJ3T2B/A** using health kit. It is with watch OS version 2.0. I used Xcode version 7.3.1 to create the app and installed it in my iPhone using diawi. I am not able to run it directly since it said deployment version of watch app is 2.2 and the one i am using is 2.0.

When i enable **Show App in Apple Watch** it is automatically getting disabled after some time in iPhone(iOS 9.3.2) watch application. Do i need to use different xcode version to create my app? I am not getting any OS updates also in my iPhone app. It says watch OS 2.0 and software is upto date.

Comment: In your project settings, you should set your Deployment Target to 2.0. About the Watch app disappearing from the Watch, I had the same problem when my developer account wasn't trusted in Settings on my iPhone, are you sure this is not the case for you?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for the reply. Yes my developer account is trusted on my iPhone. I am not able to see the iPhone app itself in the app list of **Device Management** in my iPhone. Is that normal? And also please let me know where should i change the deployment target in Xcode for watch app. I am able to see iPhone deployment target but watchOS deployment target is not visible in any of the target

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks david. The issue is due to deployment target only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got what was the issue. It is the deployment target which keeps me from installing the watch app. I changed the deployment target to 2.0 in Project->Build settings and now i am able to install the application

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to check "Window" > "Devices and Simulators". For the iPhone to which the relevant Apple Watch is paired, the name of the Apple Watch was shown as `<null>`. After unpairing the iPhone (right click > "Unpair Device") and pairing it again, the issues was gone.

Afterwards I was able to select the WatchKit App in the Schemes list and select the entry for "My iPhone + My Apple Watch" in the Device list and Run/Debug the app.

It has also sadly shown that the issue re-appears multiple times during the day and I have to repeat these steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `ClockKit.framework` as an Optional library under the watch app Extension "Link Binary With Library" Build Phases because I was using the WatchOS 5.0 function called `CLKFullColorImageProvider` which was causing the app to crash. But, before I did this, I set the deployment target to match that of the Watch OS (4.3 in my case) so the app would run from XCode and dump out the error. So, it seems that changing the deployment target is a good way to get the app to install in order to debug other problems.

I found this answer here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108598

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the Apple Watch app would fail to install my Development Apple Watch App.  I was able to finally get it installed by increasing the Bundle Number the iOS App and the WatchKit App.